# Automatically Update a JComboBox list?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, server

In the application which I am developing, multiple users can modify a model on a server, the model contains a list of objects and the users get the updated model every time a user makes changes to it.
When the client starts the program he can open a JFrame where a JComboBox appears and in this ComboBox are listed all the objects from the server. My question is now :
How to make it so that the list on this JFrame updates by itselfs,so that if let's say, another user removes an object from the list, the object is no longer being shown for the other users ,who are looking at the list at the same time?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Observer / Observable pattern?](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm) This might help you with pushing updates to other clients.

Comment: @Greg Hilston .... I agree with Observer/Observable pattern. Your comment is right...can you give the more detail by answering this question :-)

Comment: @ZinMinn Awesome, thanks man! Still trying to find out when a comment or answer is more appropriate. Answer posted

Answer (score 3):

What I think you are asking for is a perfect use case for the [Observer / Observable Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm).

Lets use your provided use case as an example. In this scenario, your server is going to act as the "Observer", as he is actively observing all your clients. Your clients are going to act as "Observables".

What happens is your server is essentially registers with all the clients to be notified if there's a change. When a client makes a change, that client will notify all Observers that registered with it (our server), who can then propgate out the changes to the clients.

We can work through some sample code together but the attached link is generally very good at explaining the Design Pattern. I figured tailoring the conversation to your use case might be helpful.

Comment: Yes, i understand that I have to inform the users for changes which were made. My problem is that I have no Idea how to implement the pattern for my classes on the client side. Let's say that I have a class Library which has as an attribute a List of Books (Book is another class). Now the user click somewhere on the GUI and a JFrame pops up in the middle of which is situated a ComboBox that lists all the Books from my Library class. Now another user removes a Book from the list - how to immediately and automatically update this ComboBox, so that the book is not shown in the list?

Comment: I'm not sure you read my answer. I provided a high level description of what you should do to implement the Observer / Observable pattern. You should take a look at that link I provided and learn about the pattern unrelated to the problem you're trying to solve. Once you've learned the pattern, applying it to your code should be much easier.